# How to implement upside down support for iPhone X, XS, 11?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Known fact that there is not native upside-down support on newest iPhones like iPhone X, XS, 11, and at the bigger versions. But I've seen some apps support this mode and autorotate on orientation changed even on these models. It seems not difficult to make an affine transform and rotate the interface by 180 degrees. But how to detect that iPhone has changed orientation without a notification? Only accelerometer and some inhouse code? Are there any frameworks or may be native solutions to detect updisde-down mode rotation?

Answer (score 0):

It works if you add this to app delegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask 
{
    return .portraitUpsideDown
}
```